# There is a ring around the image which is added to the window. How do I remove it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I added an image in my window. The background color is white. The image is white as well but there is a ring around it which separated the image with the window. How do I remove that black ring around the image ?

Here is the screenshot of the window : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtIHL.jpg

````
window = tk.Tk()
window.configure()

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 800  # width for the Tk root
h = 600  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()
canvas_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, command=canvas.yview)
canvas_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas_scroll.set, scrollregion=())


photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/logo.png")
label = tk.Label(canvas, image=photo)
canvas.create_window(125,10, window=label, anchor=tk.NW)


l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="강재 NESTING 최적화 프로그램", font= "calibri 32",fg="royalblue4",bg="white" )
canvas.create_window(125,70, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)


l1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MIN")
canvas.create_window(125,150, window=l1, anchor=tk.NW)


l2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MAX")
canvas.create_window(260,150, window=l2, anchor=tk.NW)


l3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 폭(SW)")
canvas.create_window(3,170, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

minw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minw_var)
canvas.create_window(190,180, window=entry_minw_number)

maxw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxw_var)
canvas.create_window(325,180, window=entry_maxw_number)

l4 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 높이(SH)")
canvas.create_window(3,190, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

minl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minl_var)
canvas.create_window(190,200, window=entry_minl_number)

maxl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxl_var)
canvas.create_window(325,200, window=entry_maxl_number)

l5 = tk.Label(canvas, text="소요 Component 개수")
canvas.create_window(3,210, window=l5, anchor=tk.NW)

rect_var = tk.IntVar()
entry_rect_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rect_var)
canvas.create_window(260,220, window=entry_rect_number)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: maybe it is part of image - did you check image in other program?  Or it is part of Label - use `create_image` with `image` and without `Label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is part of `Label` so use `create_image` to put image on `Canvas` without `Label`

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/logo.png")
canvas.create_image(125,10, image=photo, anchor=tk.NW)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is default border of canvas which can be removed just by adding `highlightthickness=0` to the canvas

**Change this**

`canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=800, height=600)`

**With this**

`canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=800, height=600, highlightthickness=0)`

Comment: @DevinMaharjan Can you add the logo to your post so I can test it?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VLwT.png, I don't get any border on my system I'm using Mac though